# building apk file on react native project

Tags: android, android-studio, react-native, apk, building

I have a react native project, I successfully built for IOS, but I am trying to build apk for android with no luck,
when I run the app on emulator it runs perfectly, but when I generate apk and run on my real device it shows no data

this is when I generate apk from android studio and run on real device 
https://i.postimg.cc/D0kzg9hd/Screenshot-20190418-164102.jpg
no data is downloaded

tried to run react-native start while generating apk with no luck,
even metro packager is not running while generating apk

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Android Studio for making APK or using the official way? Just let me know. This may happen if you try to do by Android Studio. However, please check if you are following the steps in this [link](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android)
Good luck!

Comment: I am using android studio to build apk

Comment: So try with the link I left then let me know ;)

Comment: I found out that the app is not working on Android 9 or api 28 ??! How to solve this problem?